# Options for improving interactive Altair line charts with many rows

Tags: python, pandas, altair

My requirement is to plot a pandas dataframe with a shape of (50,000, 2) as an **interactive line chart**. One column contains `datetime64[ns]`, and the other contains floating point integers.

Unfortunately, it appears that with this much data, the interactive chart becomes quite slow to **pan-and-zoom**. My chart is very basic, and I can observe that once I decrease the # of rows to < ~10,000, the performance becomes noticeably better. I have read the [FAQ](https://altair-viz.github.io/user_guide/faq.html) and understand that the official guidelines doesn't even recommend more than 5,000 rows to begin with. Nevertheless, I am looking for ways to improve performance, and there doesn't seem to be a lot discussion on this

I don't need to display all 50,000 data points at once, but I do want all 50,000 stored in a self-contained .html file (ie, chart).

I am thinking along the lines of "Saving plot to disk", "Using a slider to create a sliding window effect that limits the number of data points that is displayed at once, "Use a more efficient data type", "Changing the appearance of the lines so that it's less intensive to render". Really, anything that might help is fine. For some context, I am comparing the performance against more dedicated visualization software like Matlab, in which I have no problem making an interactive line chart with this much data.

Alternatively, I'm also happy to hear an explanation for why this much data isn't feasible to plot interactively due to constraints in HTML, JSON, Altair, Vega, or whatever else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are undergoing efforts to make Vega more performant (including via WebGL), which you can read about here https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/2619. Until those land, I think you best bet is to zoom into a smaller area, which sound like it could work well since you mentioned not needing to display all points at once. I find that using the data_server backend can also help with some large data slow downs, although not anything rendering related.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import altair as alt


alt.data_transformers.enable('data_server')

N=50000
test_df = pd.DataFrame({'t' : range(0, N, 1),
                        'A' : np.random.randint(0, 100, size=N)})

alt.Chart(test_df).mark_point().encode(
    alt.X('t', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[4000, 6000])),
    alt.Y('A', scale=alt.Scale(domain=[40, 60]))).interactive()
```

Comment: Thanks (again) Joel! I think fundamentally, I'm just trying to figure out whether the slowdown is caused by my bad code or a limitation in Vega. Knowing that there's no WebGL support brings me some peace of mind. On another note, I saw your comment here: https://github.com/vega/vega/issues/2619#issuecomment-825118328. Do you think it's worth a try for me to use bokeh or plotly? The charts I'm trying to build aren't terribly fancy (my goal is to just vconcat a few interactive line charts), and I'm wondering if I'm using the wrong tool for the job.

Comment: @KenLin Yup I think both plotly and bokeh (+holoviews) are good options when smooth interactivity of big datasets is principal. If you have even more data than webGL can handle, you can try out datashader which rasterizes data to images before display https://datashader.org/getting_started/Interactivity.html

Comment: Do you have a rough idea how much data would likely require rasterization? Again, it'd be building a simple interactive line chart with two columns. 100k rows? 1 million rows? It feels like you have encountered similar problems before and would have a rough idea.

Comment: @KenLin What I usually see mentioned is that tens to hundreds of thousands of points should be OK with webgl, but millions to.billions require datashader. I don't have extensive experience with this so you would want to try it out yourself.