# How to check Altair chart 's Zoom in/out functionality in a programatic way each time when i Zoom in/out in the front end

Tags: python, altair, streamlit

I have written a streamlit code where I am using altair to display a chart in the front end. The made that chart to have zoom in/out functionality. I used ".interactive()" to get this done like below.

```
chart = alt.Chart(embd_1).mark_circle(size=30).encode(
    x = 'dimention1:Q', 
    y = 'dimention2:Q',
    tooltip=['col1'] ,
    color=color).properties(width=600,height=600).add_selection(selected).interactive()
```

But, I am facing a problem when I do zoom in/out in my app. It's taking lot of time to get updated. once i start scrolling the mouse, it takes literally more than 10 secs to update the zoomed chart in the front end.

I was just wondering this may be because streamlit is running all the code which is beneath the altairs code as i don't know how to skip or avoid a certain code when i use zoom in/out functionality.

So, The question is how to programatically define whether the user is zooming in/out ?

like below :

```
if CheckZoom_SomeThingIDnotKnowYet == True:
   logic to execute code1
else:
   logic to execute code2
```

Additional Info On data and Altair Code used:

```
def altair_graph(embd_1):
    selected = alt.selection_single(on="click", empty="none")
    dom = ['Other IPs', 'Slected IP','Sel Dims']
    rng_clr = ['lightgrey', 'red','blue']

    color_point=alt.Color('color', scale=alt.Scale(domain=dom, range=rng_clr))

    color = alt.condition(selected, alt.value('red'), color_point,legend=None)

    chart = alt.Chart(embd_1).mark_circle(size=30).encode(
        x = 'dimention1:Q', 
        y = 'dimention2:Q',
        tooltip=['dimention1','dimention2'] ,
        color=color
    ).properties(width=600,height=600).add_selection(selected).interactive()

    return chart
```

And Sample for the above function Can be created like below:

```
dimention1=np.random.rand(1,100000).squeeze()
dimention2=np.random.rand(1,100000).squeeze()
colr_values = ['Other Ids', 'Slected Id','Sel Dims']
color = np.random.choice(colr_values, 100000, p=[0.9, 0.05, 0.05])
sample = pd.DataFrame({'dimention1':dimention1,'dimention2':dimention2,'color':color})
```

```
altair_graph(sample)
```

As shown in the example, My real time data is more than 150k data points.

Even When I have executed the above code outside streamlit, This is taking significant time to zoom in/out. Could ssomeone please provide a workaround for this problem.

Comment: Could your provide a reproducible example with data and code? You can try running the Altair chart outside of streamlit to find out if it is related to streamlit or Altair (probably the latter).

Comment: @joelostblom - I have added the sample data and code I am using in the above description. And, yeah it is taking longer time outside the streamlit too.

Answer (score 0):

Altair/VegaLite is a the moment not very performant with that many data points (I think it slows down around 20-40k somewhere). You can try `alt.data_transformers.enable('data_server')` for potential minor improvements and see my answer here for some more details and discussion in the comments https://stackoverflow.com/a/67349827/2166823.